# Pygame hold key down causes an infinite loop

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to write a Pong game in which I can move the paddle using the up and down arrows. I created a Paddle object that updates by a given amount (passed as the parameter "num" in the code below) each time the up key is pressed. What I want to do is allow the user to hold the up button down which would cause the paddle to continuously move in the up direction. I tried writing this event handling in a while loop, but I got stuck in an infinite loop. Here is the code below:

```
    for event in PE.get():
        if event.type == PG.KEYDOWN:
            keystate = PG.key.get_pressed()
            if event.key == PG.K_ESCAPE:
                done = True
            while keystate[PL.K_UP]:
                rightPaddle.update(-20)


        if event.type == PG.QUIT:
            done = True
```

Below is the code for the Paddle object:

```
    class Paddle(object):

def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.topleftx = x
    self.toplefty = y
    self.width = 15
    self.height = 100

def draw(self, surface):
    rect = PR.Rect(self.topleftx, self.toplefty, \
                        self.width, self.height)
    surface.fill(WHITE, rect)

def update(self, num):
    self.toplefty += num
```

I checked other stackoverflow questions on this topic, which is how I found the PG.key.getPressed() method, but other answers suggest using "sprites" which I'm not sure how to use. Could anyone offer some advice on how to go about performing this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the while loop is that it's evaluating the one keydown event. That event will always be whatever it starts as, and there's no chance for it to change within the event handling code. What you want to catch is the PG.KEYUP event that follows it. So you'll have something (logically) like

```
if event.type == PG.KEYDOWN and keystate[PL.K_UP]:
    key_up_pressed = True
elif event.type == PG.KEYUP and keystate[PL.K_UP]:
    key_up_pressed = False
```

Obviously, you can factor that better, but the `key_up_pressed` state will get evaluated in your main loop once every so often (frame, millisecond, whatever), and move the paddle.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I understand why the infinite loop is occurring now, but I can't seem to come up with a way to get around it. Even if I define a key_up_pressed variable, where should I put the update() method? Should it still be in the event driven for loop?

Comment: No, it should be in the main loop of your program. SDL (and Pygame) programs are usually structured with a main loop that processes events, draws to the screen, and does things that need doing (updating physics, etc.) You want to put this in there, so it can be updated frequently. Once it's moving in the right direction, try to decouple it from frame rate.

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
while keystate[PL.K_UP]:
    rightPaddle.update(-20)
```

… there is nothing that can change `keystate`. So, if `keystate[PL.K_UP]` is true once, it will be true forever. Hence the infinite loop.

You could fetch the current key information from pygame each time through the loop, which would at least make it not infinite—but it would still mean your entire program blocks up until the user releases the key.

Without knowing whether you intended to write a frame-rate-driven game or an event-loop-driven game, I can't tell you exactly how to fix it.

But either way, the key point is that you don't want to move over and over as long as the key is held down, you want to move at a certain speed, processing other events in between, as long as the key is held down. Either way, you'll use the KEYDOWN and KEYUP events to set some kind of flag that tells you to move the paddle. Then, once per frame, or using a timer event, or in some other way, you will use the current flag value to move the paddle.