# How to hold a 'key down' in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.7

I use Pygame 1.9.6 and Python 3.7.4. I want to hold down the space bar and it continuously does the same action over and over. I know how to have have the button get pressed with `KEYDOWN`. I looked at the question: [How to efficiently hold a key in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093662/how-to-efficiently-hold-a-key-in-pygame) for answers but can't understand the one answer:

```
while not done: 
    keys = key.get_pressed() 
    if keys[K_DOWN]: 
        print "DOWN" 
    for e in event.get(): 
        pass # proceed other events. 
            # always call event.get() or event.poll() in the main loop
```

I don't get the `key.get_pressed()`. It's not from Pygame. Also, I'm assuming it's a function they wrote, but this doesn't show me on when I hold down a 'Key' it continues to run that action and when the 'Key' is released it stops the action being called. Any pointers on how to actually hold down a button or how to make one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) is a function form [`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) module. It returns a list of boolean values representing the state of every key on the keyboard.

If you want to test if the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key is pressed the you have to get the state of `K_SPACE` by subscription:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    # [...]
```